# npm - install explained

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I'm trying to grasp how npm install works.

[image: On Npm install]

Shouldn't this have installed all the dependencies in package.json ?

I wen't to the docs [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

> npm install (in package directory, no arguments):
>     Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.

**1)**

What i understood is when invoking **npm install** This package.json (/protractor/package.json) is not the place where npm will look for dependencies in the folder i am currently in.

In **/node_modules** there a are a bunch of packages each with it's own package.json 
Why are they not getting installed ?

**2)**

When first cloning the app , i wen't into the root folder invoked **npm install** 
And node models were created , and all the dependecies in ~/angular-phonecat/package.json were installed.

Why doesn't it work the same way from inside the protractor folder ? 
Does it have something to do with the warning above ?

Comment: The dependencies are probably already installed.

Comment: if i erase it or call npm update would they be re installed ?
O'k npm update re-installed every thing as expected.

Comment: I'm building up to a larger question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in an installed package.  When you install protractor it automatically installs all it's dependencies because protractor is an NPM package.  If you delete the "node_modules" folder in there and type npm install, it will reinstall everything.  Note: this is not the purpose of npm.

NPM is used for when you have your own project and you store it on a repository, you can add all the dependencies so when a user downloads the repository they can just type npm install to get the dependencies from npm.